# Write to a file though a $_get variable

Tags: php

So i am trying to use a certin code to write to a file (The Get Param is sent by a game and i can confirm it is being sent), heres the code:

```
<?php

$Player = htmlspecialchars($_GET["Player"]);
$open = fopen("joins.txt","w+");
fwrite($open, "Player {$Player} Joined.\n");
fclose($open);

echo "$Player Logged!";
?>
```

heres the end of the url that matters in this:

```
addjoinlog.php?player=PlayerNameHere
```

When it logs, it just puts this in it:

```
Player  Joined.

and not Player PlayerNameHere Joined
```

Is something wrong with my code because i've tried different things and nothings works.

Comment: player!=Player case matters

Comment: I already tried that, it didn't make a difference.

Comment: post your new ode, because it an issue with the above code `addjoinlog.php?player=PlayerNameHere` =>`addjoinlog.php?Player=PlayerNameHere`

Comment: Nevermind, it was the case, i changed it in the games code and it worked, dont know why but i tried it before and it didnt work

Comment: i find that unlikely, but glad it works now

Comment: `$_GET["Player"]` need to be `$_GET["player"]`. Also `{}` is not required inside `fwrite`. do like this:-`fwrite($open, "Player $Player Joined.\n");`

Answer (score -2):

Try file_put_contents to write file

```
    $output = print_r($_GET, true); 
    $myfile = file_put_contents('log.txt', $output.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: for a start it was an issue with the variable name case, read the comments, and then all you suggest is to change what is written to the file, how does this "answer" anything?